# How to play a MovieClip x times

Tags: movieclip, createjs, easeljs

The MovieClip class in the EaselJS module has a loop property which can be set to true or false, causing the movie clip to play infinitely or only once. http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html

I need to play a movie clip (banner ad) three times.  How can that be done?

This is the init function:

```html
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
 // --- write your JS code here ---
 
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 images = images||{};

 var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
 loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
 loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
 loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
 if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
 exportRoot = new lib.banner_728x90();

 stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
 stage.addChild(exportRoot);
 stage.update();
 stage.enableMouseOver();

 createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no loop count support, nor any events from MovieClip indicating when an animation finishes. The latter isn't a bad idea, feel free to log a bug in [GitHub](http://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues).

One solution you could use would be to dispatch some custom events from a timeline script in Animate:

```
this.dispatchEvent("walkend");
```

Then you can listen for the event, and handle it yourself.

```
var loopCount = 0;
exportRoot.myClip.on("walkend", function(event) {
    loopCount++;
    if (loopCount > 2) {
        doSomething();
        event.remove(); // No longer get this event.
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Lanny.  Your response was instrumental in finding the solution.  A Tween has a complete event.  I used that from the last tween in the clip to trigger a function similar to the one in your answer.